# Bicycle Racing Topics?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic, questions

Are [racing](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/racing) / [racing-training](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/racing-training) questions ok for this site?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As long as its bicycle racing, I see no reason why not.

Answer (score 6):

Most certainly! I'd rather we not get questions following celebrity racers, but questions about racing are welcome.

If you have a question that's on the edge of cycling-or-no, have a look at the existing threads in meta where we debate this on other topics. (Generally, anything with the [on-off-topic tag](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-off-topic), which you've already used for this question.)

Starting your own thread (like this) is a good step, because we can point to this later on when someone asks for a policy on [topic].

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be quite useful to discuss racing, but it will be important to keep it to tactics, strategies and rules and to not allow it to drift off into "who's going to win the Tour/Vuelta/Giro/Worlds/etc." though.

While there are going to be region-related questions, I don't think that's a problem. Asking about how the British racing points system works might not be of interest to someone in Canada - but that's like a JAVA developer not being interested in a question on Erlang.

Answer (score 1):

Bike racing is notoriously hard to get into, so for someone starting out, this could be an invaluable resource.

That aside, there are tons of very legit questions on training, tactics, race prep, etc that would be valuable to have here.

I do think this is an example of a topic that localized questions and answers should be allowed though. Bike racing in $AREA_1 might be very different from $AREA_2. Rules and regulations, upgrade policies, where to take a 'learn to race' course, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure about allowing localized questions, but we can certainly discuss on a case-by-case basis and set some precedents. How many racers do we have that frequent meta and can help set policy on this? Racers are more likely to understand fine distinctions. 

A question asking "what's the rule for [thing] in [location]?" would be viewed differently than "why does [location] have [particular rule]?"  

These sites were conceived originally for programming-related questions, where there's more often a single correct answer, so we need to remain flexible.

Comment: One of the things with racing rules is that, I believe, worldwide they are set by the UCI (Union Cycliste Internationale, the world peak organisation), and there is very little local variation.  So it is possible to discuss the rules and have it be applicable to just about everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others that racing should be included. There are a bunch of useful questions that could be asked on learning to race and race specific training. I think that it's most important to make sure that novice racers are catered to though.

Answer (score 0):

I am very supportive of questions that delve into riding itself and complement the more gear-headed aspects of the Q&A, but I have one question:

How would the board deal with the resulting questions about nutrition and dietary supplements though? Are these fair game or would they end up being closed as no on topic, or referred to a nutrition board? There was a question about cramping that was answered directly, but I can see problems with other more sprawling food/vitamin recommendations cropping up outside of a CW.

Comment: Its worth opening up a new question for this. I'd recommend following Neilfeins example of posting your sample question (to see what kind of responses you get), plus post a question about it on meta. (e.g.  http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/34/commuting-question-why-is-this-on-topic-or-is-it)

Comment: So far this appears to be the only one listed under the topic, http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/603/what-is-the-best-breakfast-right-before-cycling. Looks like a normal thread, it just seems that maybe this type of discussion should be listed as CW?