# Are questions on professional cycling races on topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic, asking-questions

Are questions relating to rules or common practices of the Tour de France, Giro d'italia etc appropriate here?

By that I mean a question that is solely to do with being a *fan* of the sport as opposed to actually participating in it.

I realise a consensus was reached four years ago in [this](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/on-or-off-topic-watching-racing) question, however as a commenter noted Sports.SE has surfaced since then which may (or may not) be more appropriate.

tl;dr: Should I ask TDF related questions here or on Sports.SE?

Comment: I vaguely remember one question, where the Op was asking where they could buy footage of professional races, got closed on the grounds that it was looking for a product rec. But I've seen several questions on the actual races over the 3 years or so, so I would say that, empirically,  they are fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I think so.

From my *brief* look at [sports.se] it seems to a be a catch-all for sports not covered by a dedicated site such as [cycling.se]. It seems to me that questions about cycling would be equally on topic here *and* there, provided the question has a definite answer.

I suggest you try one and see how it flies.

Comment: The question I tried along these lines was well received. I think we can take from the reception that questions of this nature are fine in general. It's not like the site is overwhelmed with questions on strictly riding bikes, and that these questions would clog it up further

Answer (score 1):

The existence of another SE site where a question would be on-topic, does not affect whether or not a question is on-topic here. Sites will have some overlap.

Yes, questions of that type are on topic on this site, as discussed in the prior question.