# On/Off topic - race strategy, from the POV of a viewer?

Tags: discussion

Recently we had a well-received question about 
 [why Pogačar responded to attacks from Roglič and from van Aert in stage 11 of this year's Tour de France](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/89507/why-did-poga%c4%8dar-respond-to-rogli%c4%8ds-and-van-aerts-attacks-in-stage-11-of-tdf-2023).

---

**Bicycles.SE**'s [tour] describes our site's purpose as:

> Bicycles is a question and answer site for people who ride, repair, or build bicycles.

To me that has a strong personal component, of doing or participating directly in the riding or repair or event.

On the other hand, **Sports.SE** purpose is:

> Sports is for participants, hobbyists, and fans of all sports and forms of competitive physical activity.

This would encompass fans attending a race but not racing, and those who have no chance to ever attend in person and can only watch broadcast coverage.

---

Additionally, Sports.SE has 113 questions [tagged as Strategy](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) although it runs the range of all sports.  By comparison, Bicycles.SE has none tagged as Strategy, and 10 tagged specifically as [racing-strategy](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/racing-strategy)

**Question**:  The original question itself is well written but has gained no answers after 14 days.  I suggest migrating it to Sports.SE to see if it does better there, with the realisation that it is now an additional two weeks removed from the event.

What do you think?   Should "armchair racing" be on the Sports.SE side or the Bicycles.SE side of the fuzzy border ?

Comment: I'm not trying to be insulting with the phrase "armchair racing" but I'm trying to distinguish between a race that you're riding in, vs a race that you're watching remotely.

Comment: Also, SE has thrown up a potential duplicate from 12 years ago at https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/on-or-off-topic-watching-racing Back then the consensus was "on-topic"   but that was a long time ago - still valid ?    UPDATE: that other question was posted before Sports.SE existed.

Answer (score 5):

Questions about racing, even professional racing, are within the scope of the [On Topic](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) portion of the Help Center:

> Bicycles Stack Exchange is for people who build and repair bicycles,
> people who train cycling, or commute on bicycles.
>
> **Most questions regarding bicycles**, tricycles, unicycles, handcycles, **and their use** are on topic for this site. (emphasis
> added)

Racing definitely qualifies as use of a bicycle. While questions about observations in professional races may seem esoteric, they can have practical applications for amateur racers. Many riders on this site have likely participated in races, and some may even participate in amateur stage races. Furthermore, all professionals start out as amateurs and, as such, future pros might glean some knowledge about racing from this site.

As far as whether or not to migrate that specific post, I suggest that we leave it up to the OP. It may do better on Sports SE. It may not. Based on the [cycling questions](https://sports.stackexchange.com/search?q=cycling) I see there and the *very* limited number of [cycling strategy](https://sports.stackexchange.com/search?q=cycling%20strategy) questions, I suspect the latter.

Since it's not off topic, it should be up to the OP where it lives.

Answer (score 1):

If as moderator, you need to apply the 'corporate policies', there's no discussion: it's off-topic, the descriptions are clear.

But pragmatically and personally, I'm not 100% convinced that it makes sense in that kind of situation to have a strict separation, and it's better to have the question answered than not: I imagine that a good part of the non-regular audience comes from Google searches and not using the internal search engine of each stack.

So moving it to sport.se might be a move to have the question answered.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, a bit late to the party on this question, think i might have been on holiday when it was posted.

Anyway, i think it's a tricky grey area.  Strictly speaking i think its on topic, it's about riding bicycles.

However without access to the riders data we simply don't have all the information needed to answer it - i could see a strong argument to vote close as opinion based.

Taking both those into account, i decided that i couldn't decide and didnt take any actions on that question.

My gut feeling is that it would be more likely to get an answer on Sports.SE, but that's a call the OP should probably make rather than being forced by moderation.